# The order of answers does not work as expected

Tags: support, accepted-answer, self-answer

In most of the questions if the answers are ordered by votes, the accepted answer would appear first (no matter how many votes it had) and all other answers would then follow, ordered by votes.

However, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878662/how-to-display-ruby-on-rails-form-validation-error-messages-one-at-a-time?answertab=votes#tab-top), where the accepted answer is after the answer with most votes. Is this because the author has selected their own answer as best?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, if the OP accepts their own answer it doesn't stick to the top of the answer list.

There have been calls in the past for the accepted answer not to stick to the top regardless, but nothing's been implemented. Indeed it's been officially declined:

> [Can we exempt downvoted accepted answers from getting the top spot?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178439/can-we-exempt-downvoted-accepted-answers-from-getting-the-top-spot)